# I want use helm range for below code to iterate its with proper indentation

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to iterate the list from **Values.yaml** through range in helm.
So how to use the range function in helm for below list?

**Values.yaml**

```
Service:
    - name: jenkins-db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
    - name: jenkins-ui
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `{{ range $item := .Values.Service }}...{{ end }}` to iterate through the loop, though this has nothing in particular to do with indentation.  Is there a more specific problem you're having?  What does your existing template code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
{{- range .Values.Service }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
spec:
  selector:
    app: {{ .name }}
  ports:
    - protocol: {{ .protocol }}
      port: {{ .port }}
      targetPort: {{ .port }}
---
{{- end }}
```

Comment: No i want to iterate that list in service.yaml from values.yaml so it will not work like this.

Comment: You want to create k8s service manifests based on the list of services that you're defining in `values.yaml`?

Comment: yes u are correct!

Comment: {{- range $key, $value := .Values.service }}
  {{- range }}
{{- end }}
  type: ClusterIP
{{- end }} ...... i need similar kind of approach because i dont want keep  these values in Service.yaml

Comment: I don't understand. Which values don't you want to keep in `values.yaml`?